# How to select values out of many in pandas dataframe using conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a CSV with multiple values for a single value and I have to filter them out based on several conditions. Below is an example of my data.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
data=[['Afghanistan','2.7;2.7','27.0;26.7','','22.9;22.8'],
    ['Bahrain','6.3;6.3;6.4','13.0;13.0;13.0','16.8;17.0',''],
    ['Djibouti','3.0;3.0;3.0','2.0','','23.1;24']],
columns=['Country', '2019', '2018', '2017', '2016'])
```

Following are the conditions to use to filter:

1. if the values are duplicated, select one.
2. if the values differ and the difference is less than 0.5,
   for eg. 26.7 and 27.0, we select 26.7 as we want to preserve the precision and would discard the rounding offs
   eg. 6.7 and 6.8, preserving both as both give precision. However, this contradicts the 0.5 rule, so taking any is also okay
3. If the values differ and the difference is more than 0.5, select both
   eg. 23.1 and 24, select both

Below is my desired output for this example.

```
desired_op = pd.DataFrame(
data=[['Afghanistan','2.7','26.7','','22.9;22.8'],
    ['Bahrain','6.3;6.4','13.0','16.8',''],
    ['Djibouti','3.0','2.0','','23.1;24']],
columns=['Country', '2019', '2018', '2017', '2016'])
```

This is a small example of the dataset. To conduct this operation, I have to convert the values to numeric format first, However, the row headings (country) and column headings(year) still have to be a string. I have more than 20 columns, and more than 50 datasets so converting each column's data to numeric is also not feasible. Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

Use from apply method for each col

```py
def f(x):
    a = x.split(';')
    if cond1:
        return ...
    if cond2:
        return ...
    if cond3:
        return ...
df['2019']=df['2019'].apply(f)
...
```

For your many cols you can do:

```py
for i in df.columns:
    if i != 'country':
        df[i]=df[i].apply(f)
```

also you can put your dataframes to a list and with a for loop iterate on each df and do above operations

for example you can remove duplicate such as below:

```py
def f(x):
    a=x.split(';')
    if len(a)>len(set(a)):
        return ';'.join(list(set(a)))
```

it returns a string value

Comment: can you help me drop just the duplicates and no more conditions

Comment: @khushbu yes I can. add this to my answer

Comment: Because I could not follow your pseudo code to get the result I want so asking to leave conditions and just remove duplicates. Since, the problem has not been solved, I can't accept as answer

Comment: @khushbu in the definition of f function, you have an input form as string that contain your values for applying your condition. it is very easy to write this condition. but I write the drop duplicates condition from values for you and you can copy it. what is your problem?

Comment: I lose a lot of values this way

Comment: I think while applying the f function over my data frame, I have to take a particular cell and not the whole column at once. I should have one more variable representing the row of the data frame. For eg. df[i][j] = df[i][j].apply(f). The j should start from 0 to the number of rows. How do I write j?

Comment: @khushbu please read the official pandas docs for apply method. when using this method, eacg row in dataframe passed to the function and you dont need to use from [j] index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246965/discussion-between-khushbu-and-alireza).